# One word for something belonging to an era

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word which means "of or relating to a particular era"?  I am looking for a word which means that something is limited to a particular era, as opposed to being universal.  Preferably it should be conjugated from the word era, but doesn't have to be.

As an example, things that only existed during the Stone Age, or practices that were only practiced before World War II, or beliefs that were prevalent before the Industrial Revolution, or technology which existed after the advent of computers, could be said to be [insert word here].

EDIT:

I have made several attempts to clarify what I am asking for, and I seem to be having trouble communicating.  "Particular" can mean "an individual object, as contrasted with a universal" - see definition 11 [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/particular).  I am looking for a word that says a noun belongs to any one era, as opposed to belonging to all eras.  "Food" would not be described with this term, as "food" belongs to any era.  "Automobile" would, as "automobile" only existed during the Modern Era and not before.  "Uncharted territory" only existed in the era before satellite imagery (at least as far as Earth is concerned).  I am *not* looking for a word which is confined to *any one particular era*.  I am looking for a word which is confined to any one era in the set of all eras.

Comment: "*Contemporary (with)*", or part of the "*zeitgeist*".

Comment: @DanBron I am not looking for a word which connotes in relation to something else.  I am looking for relating to a particular era as opposed to being universally relevant.

Comment: Ah, the first word that comes to mind for me is "***period***", as in "*[period dress](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GorgeousPeriodDress)*" in cinema.

Comment: *That document is from the Edo period.* But the word you're looking for is something like *eral* or *periodal*.

Comment: @DanBron So would periodic be the conjugation?

Comment: @YEZ, No, "*periodic*" means "*regularly occuring*" or "*at a predictable frequency*". Try "*periodal*" from SrJoven's comment (I've never heard "*eral*" used, but that doesn't mean you can't).

Comment: @SrJoven Are either of those real words?  They don't come up in any dictionary on a Google search.

Comment: Context in the form of an appropriate sentence may be of interest to get a correct answer. I simply suggested the types of words that apply to your comment to answers below. My suggestions aren't really correct or understood by people, but would apply as contextual examples to the type of word you seem to seek. (A guess of what you want. Something like "That's an Edo *periodal* document.") though "That's an Edo *period* document" is more likely to be understood.

Comment: There's the geological term 'erathem'. Don't know how you'd use it outside of that field, but it does mean 'of or relating to a particular era', but it's specifically relating to rocks.

Comment: @SrJoven Thanks for the suggestion - example added.

Comment: Why the downvotes?  Am I missing something?

Comment: I think the problem is that you want something that is related to a *particular* era, but then are asking for a general term that means related to *an* era. In use this is of no value:  *This chair is from an era.* Yes, ok, and??  To be of use you should identify the *particular* era:  *This chair is Victorian.*  Now, I don't need to use your word at all; I just use the adjective for the *particular era* in question. And if you don't know the particular era, you can just say it's *antique* ;-)

Comment: @Jim Then you misunderstood my use of the word "particular."  "Particular" means as opposed to general.  I am not looking for relating to _one_ specific era, rather for _any_ specific era.  I _don't have_ a particular era in mind - I have _particularity_ in mind, which is how I asked the question, and how I gave examples to illustrate.  I don't know how to make it clearer - I stated explicitly that I meant particular as opposed to universal.

Comment: Ok, *obsolete*, *out-dated*, *old* all fit in your sentence.

Comment: @Jim Right, if you take my example out of context from my preceding description, you're correct.  As an _illustration_ of the preceding description, I think it is quite clear that those would not work.

Comment: How could a word be both generally applicable and also specifically identifying an era? Eras are not rigourously defined. Everything belongs to any infinite set of arbitrary eras. Let's say the word is blimzprodal. That word specifically says that a chair belongs to an era. How would you expect that word to be used?

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 I don't understand what you mean.  Does "food" belong to any particular era to the exclusion of others?  How about "oxygen" or "laws of physics"?  On top of that, eras do have a degree of definition.  A period of time qualified by a particular attribute.  I don't understand your example of a word that means "a chair belongs to an era" - I am not looking for a word which refers to a specific object.  I am looking for a word which describes a state of being.

Comment: "food" is abstract. Pizza belongs to the modern era. Mammoth steaks belong to the stone age. How would you expect to be able to describe "mammoth steaks" with your hypothetical word?

Comment: Maybe you should clarify what you mean by something belonging to an era.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 Why is "food" abstract but "pizza" isn't?  Is  it Pepperoni Pizza or whole wheat pizza or extra cheese?  I can point to that food over there - am I pointing to an abstract?  And if "globish" meant "something belonging to an era" then mammoth stakes would be globish.

Comment: So if mammoth steaks are globbish, what is pizza? What about dinosaur steaks (assuming some creature ever ate those)?

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 I don't know why dinosaur steaks aren't also globish, and I'm not sure why you're implying that's a problem.  Pizza can be globish too, if it is confined to a particular time.  Just like they all could be yellow, and that won't bother anyone!  One word can describe more than one object.

Comment: My point was that everything belongs to an era. Anyone can define any era as any points in time. So what use is a word that indicates that something belongs to an era then? Everything is globish.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 and what about my example which you ignored before?  Are the laws of physics globish?  Or "oxygen"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17242/discussion-between-mr-shiny-and-new--and-yez).

Comment: Are you looking for *of a different era* or *a thing of the past*?  E.g.,  That idea is *a thing of the past* or *That whole concept is from a different era.*

Answer (score 4):

Something may be *contemporaneous* with other things of the same era.

Answer (score 4):

*Epoch* might serve the purpose.

> a particular period of time marked by distinctive features, events, etc.:

Examples at: http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/epoch

Comment: Probably "epochal" would be closer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> a word which means that something is limited to a particular era, as opposed to being universal

*Dated* is a word that means that, at least wrt a **past** era. Example:

- The expression *Duck and cover!* is dated, as is the associated concept.

Or perhaps you are just looking for a word like *time-related*, *time-relevant*, or *era-specific*, which conveys the idea that the thing in question is not meaningful for all times/eras?

Answer (score 1):

[*Coeval*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Coeval) may convey the idea.  The Free Dictionary defines *coeval* as:

> Originating or existing during the same period; lasting through the same era.

Comment: Thanks -  I am not looking for a word which connotes in relation to something else. I am looking for relating to a particular era as opposed to being universally relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen *current* used in this manner, when context is understood as the period in question.  Synonyms *prevalent, prevailing* could also work.

Answer (score 0):

*Temporary*: lasting for only a limited period of time; not permanent (as per Google).